# HSQLDB embarcado

Tags: java, hsqldb

Olá.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Java com HSQLDB.
Quando acesso o banco de dados com caminho absoluto, funciona tudo ok:

String txtCon = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/ITA/workplace/hsqldb-2.3.3/hsqldb/db/crudfx";

Daí coloquei a pasta db dentro do meu projeto e estou tentando acessa-la por caminho relativo:

String txtCon = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:db/crudfx";

E não funciona de forma alguma... o que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Como está a hierarquia do seu projeto? Qual IDE está usando? Eu uso esse db com caminho relativo de uma pasta dentro do projeto e nunca tive problemas

Comment: E outra você diz que não funciona, dá algum erro(pilha de exceção no app)? Porque até onde sei, quando não encontra o banco do path informado, o hsql cria um banco novo vazio, e o erro deve ser por isso.

Comment: Uso o Eclipse. 
Diego F, poderia mostrar como você apresenta o caminho relativo?
O erro é que ele não encontra as tabelas.

Comment: Cara edita sua resposta, tá superficial demais, não da pra saber o problema se você não fornecer mais detalhes. Leia meu segundo comentário, talvez ajude a resolver.